# How to find the Mongodb credentials from the config file?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've recently joined to a project that uses Mongodb. I'm a newbie to this database. I need to find the database credentials to get an export of it (as a backup) before everything.

The [doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/connect/) says, the `connect()` method would have these parameters:

```
connect(url, user, password)
```

But I don't see that syntax in the real project. Here is the content of `mongoose.js` file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(
  'mongodb://bpAdmin:Bp1400#@32.150.189.207:27017/bpDB?authSource=admin',
  {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    autoIndex: true,
  }
);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

module.exports = {
  mongoose,
};
```

(The IP and some other names just changed because of some security reasons)

Could you please tell me **what's the user and password and db name?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the format in [offical documentation on connection string](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/),

> mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]

So for your questions,

| info | value |
| --- | --- |
| username | bpAdmin |
| password | Bp1400# |
| db name used for auth | admin |
| default db to connect to | bpDB |